# EPSG code has stopped working with pyproj.Transformer.from_crs, but still works with pyproj.transform and pyproj.Proj

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, epsg, pyproj

My code:

```
from pyproj import Proj, Transformer

EASE_Proj = 'EPGS:3409'
    
WGS_Proj = 'EPSG:4326'

transformer = Transformer.from_crs(WGS_Proj, EASE_Proj)
```

Suddenly produces the following error after an update of pyproj:

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: EPGS:3409: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)
```

Bafflingly, if I use the Northern hemisphere projection EPGS:3408, the code runs fine!

Does anybody know how I can fix this? I'm running pyproj version 3.1.0 on an anaconda installation, `pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir()` yields `'/home/robbie/anaconda3/share/proj'`

Even more confusingly, the following code (written in what I think is a deprecated style), still works:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:3409')
x1,y1 = lons[0], lats[0]
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print (x2,y2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There must be an older version of the EPSG definitions in the system that still works. EPSG:3409 "NSIDC EASE-Grid South" is deprecated in the EPSG database in 2020-03-30 and the reason was

> No longer supported by EPSG because datum information is required for
> unambiguous spatial referencing.

The CRS is replaced by EPSG:3932 https://epsg.org/crs_6932/WGS-84-NSIDC-EASE-Grid-2-0-South.html.

The information about deprecated EPSG items are available from https://epsg.org. Anonymous users cannot see them but anybody can register and get a user account.